# Condition for Sequence of Numbers to Have Both OGF and EGF

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

As an example, The Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind, denoted S(n,k), has two generating functions; an ordinary and an exponential.  The ordinary is

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{S(n,k)x^n}=\frac{x^k}{(1-x)(1-2x)...(1-kx)}$$

and the exponential is

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{S(n,k)\frac{x^n}{n!}}=\frac{(e^x-1)^k}{k!}$$

Is there a way to determine whether a particular sequence of numbers has both an exponential and ordinary generating function?  Not all sequences of numbers have both generating function types; Euler numbers do not appear to have both for example, and I have not found any literature stating the Bernoulli Numbers have an ordinary generating function.

Comment: This is just a thought but it may be handy to remember the connection between egf $f_{\text{e}}$ and ogf $f_{\text{o}}$ of the same sequence $$f_{\text{o}}(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}f_{\text{e}}(xt)\, \mathrm{d}t$$ perhaps this can be exploited in some way?

Comment: This is interesting.  It is similar to a Laplace Transform, but the argument of the exponential generating function has the change of variable argument.  Is this particular transformation called anything?

Comment: I'm not sure if it has a name. It exploits the gamma function property for non-negative $n$ since $$n!=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^n\,\mathrm{d}t$$ It's a convenient *tool* for expressing certain combinatorial counts, but I figured it is a nice way of connecting egfs and ogfs so it might be an indication as to whether an egf has a *nice* ogf and vice-versa. It was only a thought, I don't really know how to proceed from there but there may be some "bright spark" on mathSE who can help. You could probably use it to show that those two generating functions for Stirling numbers are equivalent.

Comment: What do you mean "have a generating function"? Do you mean one that is convergent somewhere?  Or that has a convenient formula?  Every sequence has a (formal) generating function.

Comment: I meant "have a convenient closed form" generating function.  Yes, any sequence has a generating function, but "nice closed forms" don't always exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few remarks (and interesting references).

> Given a sequence $(a_n)$ we are always free to consider different types of generating functions. Amongst them are
>
> - *[Ordinary generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Ordinary_generating_function_.28OGF.29)*
>     \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n
>   \end{align*}
> - *[Exponential generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function_.28EGF.29)*
>     \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \frac{x^n}{n!}
>   \end{align*}
> - *[Dirichlet generating functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletGeneratingFunction.html)*
>     \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{s^n}
>   \end{align*}
> - or *[Lambert series](http://dlmf.nist.gov/27.7)*
>     \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \frac{x^n}{1-x^n}
>   \end{align*}
>
> But for a specific sequence $(a_n)$ usually not all types of generating functions will provide useful results or can be represented in a closed form.

In combinatorics we typically take ordinary generating functions to count unlabelled objects and exponential generating functions when we want to count labelled objects. See e.g. the first two chapters in *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick.

> As stated in your post the ordinary generating function for Bernoulli Numbers
>
> \begin{align*}
> \beta(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n x^n=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}-\frac{x^4}{30}+\frac{x^6}{42}-\cdots
> \end{align*}
>   is rather unusual compared with the much more common exponential generating series
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_n}{n!}x^n=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{12}-\frac{x^4}{720}
> +\frac{x^6}{30240}-\cdots
> \end{align*}

In fact it is stated in *[Curious and Exotic Identities for Bernoulli Numbers](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/978-4-431-54919-2/curious-bernoulli.pdf)* by Don Zagier in section A.1 *The **other** Generating Function(s) for the Bernoulli Numbers*.

He states there that despite its being divergent and not being expressible as an elementary function, it fulfills the following functional equation:

The power series $\beta(x)$ is the unique solution in $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ of the equation
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-x}\beta\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)-\beta(x)=x
\end{align*}